# Alternate Floats in Flexbox/Container

Tags: html, css

I have a series of flexbox items that contain an image and content. I'd like to alternate which side of the flexbox item the image appears (i.e., the left side of the box in one, the right side in the next). I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions are appreciated!

**CSS**

```
.offerings {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.offeringsItem {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #dedede;

}

.offeringsContent {
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.offeringsImg {
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.offeringsImg img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.offeringsImg:nth-of-type(odd) img {
    float: right;
}

.offeringsImg:nth-of-type(even) img {
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="offerings">
    <div class="offeringsItem">
        <div class="offeringsImg">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tpd-files/images/Artboard-2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="offeringsContent">
            Hi.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="offeringsItem">
    <div class="offeringsImg">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tpd-files/images/Artboard-2.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are about using `flex`, i believe using it on `.offeringsItem` is plenty enough. and `flex-flow:row-reverse` will do the job.

```css
.offeringsItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
}

.offeringsItem:nth-of-type(odd) {
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

.offeringsContent,
.offeringsImg {
  margin: 10px;
}

.offeringsContent {
  flex: 1;
}

.offeringsImg img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="offerings">
  <div class="offeringsItem">
    <div class="offeringsImg">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tpd-files/images/Artboard-2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="offeringsContent">
      Hi.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="offeringsItem">
    <div class="offeringsImg">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tpd-files/images/Artboard-2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="offeringsContent">
      Hi.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I 'have removed some styles that did not seem necessary, it also makes the CSS update easier to read ;)

Comment: Question, though: it seems like the text inside also gets reversed to be right aligned. Any thoughts on keeping the text over to the left?

Comment: @DD1229 , yes add this :`.offeringsContent {
  flex: 1;
}` so it fills all space avalaible .(add backgrounds or shadows to your elements to see where they actually stand ) . snippet updated

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

The CSS class should be corrected to.

```
.offeringsItem:nth-of-type(odd) img {
  float: right;
}

.offeringsItem:nth-of-type(even) img {
  float: left;
}
```

Instead of applying on the div with the class `offeringsImg`, you need to apply the `nth-of-type()` selecor to the div with the class `offeringsItem` because only these elements have a common parent and the index will be taken properly, before they had separate parents hence it did not work!, One more correction is that you had missed the final closing div in the HTML.

```css
.offerings {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.offeringsItem {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
}

.offeringsContent {
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.offeringsImg {
  margin: 10px;
}

.offeringsImg img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.offeringsItem:nth-of-type(odd) img {
  float: right;
}

.offeringsItem:nth-of-type(even) img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="offerings">
  <div class="offeringsItem">
    <div class="offeringsImg">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tpd-files/images/Artboard-2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="offeringsContent">
      Hi.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="offeringsItem">
    <div class="offeringsImg">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tpd-files/images/Artboard-2.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="offeringsItem">
    <div class="offeringsImg">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tpd-files/images/Artboard-2.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using float, try using `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` on the boxes with your images